# How to attach EventEmitter2 to a div element

Tags: javascript

I'm new to EventEmitter2. My understanding is if you want to listen for an event, you would do this:

```
var EventEmitter2 = require('eventemitter2');
var server = new EventEmitter2();

server.on('touchend', test); // listen for event
server.emit('touchend'); // fire off event

function test() { console.log('hello'); }
```

What I don't understand is how do I attach the emitter to a div? In my .js file I get the div element and I want to attach a listener to that element, so I know when the user clicks on it. I'm looking for something like this:

```
someDIV.on('touchend', test)
function test() { console.log('hello'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get real event from browser and emit it to server. The meaning of EventEmitter is to make event based communications in the logic part of script. For example, your program gets data via ajax and you want to get notify in something like console.log(); so you do something like this:

```
server.on('gotAjax', function() {
   console.log(arguments);
});

//...far far at some other scope, where is only server from prev code is accessible ....
function DataRecveived(data) {
   render(data);
   server.emit('gotAjax', data); // I not remember if need to "new Event()" here
```

so in your case you should do something like

```
someDIV.addEventListener('touchend', function() {
  server.emit('touchEnd');
});
```

or, if you need to do something by touchend emited on server with your div:

```
server.on('touchend') {
   someDiv.classList.remove('touched');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is 'someDiv' is not an instance of eventEmitter2 it's a div, so it doesn't have the 'on' function. I was trying to figure out a way to use the eventEmitter2 instance wth a div, but it doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: I edited answer, the addEventListener is native event handler ;)